# Cannot Implicitly Convert Type to system.net

Tags: c#

I am having an error in my program when trying to download files from a remote server, I am using the `System.Net` Lib and it is having an issue converting to it.

I am getting the error Message

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler' to
>   System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler'

on the last line in the code block

```
AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

### Error Line ^

Form.cs  V

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace Buildcraft_Installer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStartDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            prgDownload.Visible = true;
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new
                DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new
                AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

I would be very grateful if anyone had a way to resolve this or a workaround to get the same result, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to write `client.DownloadFileCompleted` on your last line.

You currently have two calls to `DownloadProgressChanged`, one with a matching delegate type (`DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler`), one with the wrong one (`AsyncCompletedEventHandler`).

Comment: Thank you, I am relatively new to programming and I tend to make the simple mistakes but look for complicated answers, I must be going blind because I swear I read it through and through.

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect `delegate` in subscription to the event on last line.

If you use Visual Studio, write `+=` and press `Tab` key,  so the method with correct signature will be generated.

But I see that a couple of lines above you already subscribed to the same event, so my impression is that you don't use a correct event for that what you want to achieve.

There *should* be `DownloadFileCompleted` event. I *presume* that is what you want.